# How to square frequentist with algorithmic complexity definition of randomness?

Tags: random, kolmogorov-complexity

The algorithmic (Kolmogorov) complexity definition of randomness states that a random string is incompressible, yet `11111111` would not be considered random because you can compress it easily.

On the other hand, we know that each sequence has the same probability when we take the frequentist definition, so the above sequence would be as random as, let's say, `01101010`.

My question: Isn't this a contradiction? How to square both approaches with each other?

Comment: But there is no concept of random sequences in the frequentist interpretation of probability. Only a concept of random variables (and sequences of random variables). Or is there?

Comment: @Raskolnikov: I read this too, but on the other hand statements about how probable something is seem to imply that something is "more random" than something else. Don't you see some contradiction in the above?

Comment: The Kolomogorov complexity is basically the length of the smallest program which outputs the desired number. If this program is basically as long as "output <number>" , then the number is considered to be a random number. The Kolmogorov complexity has nothing to do with the probability that the particular number occurs in whatsoever experiment.

Comment: It can be proven that the Kolmogorov complexity is uncomputable , in particular in general a number cannot be proven to be random. This is closely related to the halting problem

Comment: If we choose a string randomly , then in fact every string has the same probability to be chosen, but the probability to choose a significantly compressible number is in fact very low. This is probably the relation you are wondering about.

Comment: @Peter: This is an interesting thought... could you flesh it out as an answer?

Comment: Why the downvote?!?